# How can i enable syntax highlighting for markdown files (.mdown) in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I just realized, that netbeans **does not support syntax highlighting** for markdown files.

Is there any plugin for netbeans, that enables syntax highlighting for these **.mdown** files?

Comment: There is a netbeans plugin for markdown at https://github.com/madflow/flow-netbeans-markdown and very soon the code highlighting feature may get added to that project

Comment: @TusharJoshi, you should move your comment to an answer.

Comment: @RobertB, ok I added this comment as an answer, I realized it is a answer for the question above

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UPDATE (2011-Nov-18): To answer your question precisely, there is no certified plugin for markdown available from NetBeans Update Center.  I have not seen any good plugin for NetBeans with syntax highlighting functionality for markdown language yet.

There is a emerging community contributed open source NetBeans plugin for markdown at http://github.com/madflow/flow-netbeans-markdown and very soon the code highlighting feature may get added to that project.  We should add our comments and desire for getting that plugin released soon to show the demand for that plugin, which will motivate the creator of that plugin to release it soon.

Comment: This project is incomplete, doesn't offer a nbm file and doesn't yet support syntax highlighting at all.  It is a module that will allow developers to convert markdown into html within netbeans.

Comment: @Hades, the project may be in its starting phase, but as it is an open source project, we the developers can add issues and comments to that project showing how many people are waiting for this project to get released.  This may motivate the creator of the project to expedite the development.  We can also provide request for enhancement to that project which allow us to add our functionality in that project.  If enough community demand is shown on that project site by developers this project may turn into a good one, in the long run.

Comment: Further update: this plugin is now released and listed on the Netbeans site (although not officially signed yet) and available to [download](https://github.com/madflow/flow-netbeans-markdown/releases). It works fine for me on Netbeans 7.4.